# Using relative paths in imports parameter of GDB repository configuration?

Tags: graphdb

According to the [GDB documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/configuring-a-repository.html), it seems like it should be possible to use relative paths in the imports parameter of a GDB repository configuration. But I cannot make it work! Does anyone know how relative paths are resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphDB will check the value of these two parameters:

```
            owlim:defaultNS "http://myFile1.defaultprefix.com;http://defaultNS2.com" ;
            owlim:imports "myFile1.ttl;myfile2.ttl" ;
```

Please make sure that the parameters both have the same length; otherwise, the database will not know what the default prefix for each file is.

The database will search the files in the $GDB_HOME/bin path.

**Edit on 24/04/2020:**

GraphDB uses the home directory of the process, which by default will match $GDB_HOME/bin. Still, in the general case, this is not always true so the correct way of converting the relative path into absolute is to check the home directory of the process with `sudo lsof -p <pid> | grep cwd`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the olwim-imports you will need to set owlim:defaultNS as well:

`owlim:imports "./test/input-files/owl.rdfs;" ;
owlim:defaultNS "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#;" ;`

There needs to be the same number of elements in both parameters. The defaultNS parameter sets the base URI for each imoport.

Regards,
Anton

Comment: This answer does not address the question. I am asking _how relative paths are resolved_ - if used in the `imports` parameter. I am configuring both `imports` and `defaultNS`; as stated in the GDB documentation. But I assume that `imports` are **not** resolved relative to `defaultNS`, because that would not make sense - or what?